# rails g scaffold needs explanation - form_for submits to index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand the stuff going on during the creation of an object using the pages generated by the command `rails g scaffold ModelName`.

What I don't understand is that given a model `Location`, the `_form.html.erb` form-tag looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@location) do |f| %>
```

This would, if I understand it correctly, point the form submission to location_path, which is like the index (or list) of all locations stored in the database.

Why is the form not pointing to `create` or `update`? Where on the way are the objects actually created? I'd be really grateful if someone could describe the flow here, like

- `_form.html.erb` submits to
- **create** in `locations_controller.rb` which redirects to
- **index** in `locations_controller.rb`, which renders
- `sometemplate.html.erb`

Comment: Post the `rake routes` output and your `controller code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the form submits depends on `@location.new_record?`.

If it’s a new record, it will `POST` to `locations_path`: `/locations`. That maps to `LocationsController#create`.

If it’s an existing record, it will `PUT` (or `PATCH` on newer versions of Rails) to `location_path(@location)`: `/locations/:id`. That maps to `LocationsController#update`.

As @Pavan suggests in the comment, a look at the existing routes can help with understanding routing:

```
rake routes
```